# Linking MouseEvents from one Java file to another Java File

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, chess

Some background I am developing a game in java, I am using Netbeans to build it I currently have 3 java files

- App.java
- Board.java
- Piece.java

Currently When it runs it shows the user a simple chess board with all the pieces in the right positions etc.

That is all done in Board.java

My Problem is the movement for the pieces is done in Piece.java currently I have the white pawn coded and the mouse events that control it but when i run the program the board appears along with the pieces but none of the pieces move not even the white pawn

and I am stumped to as why, I think maybe I have not linked them probably with the board or something along those lines or maybe there is something u with my mouseevents

Also I am not getting any errors in my code when it run

Here are the java files

App.java

```
package chessgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class App {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Board();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

Board.java

```
package chessgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class Board extends JFrame {

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    public Board() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  This is a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white);
            }
        }
        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        //White Side
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhitePawn.png")));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKing.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteQueen.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);

        //Black Side
        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackPawn.png")));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKing.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackQueen.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }
}
```

Piece.java

```
    package chessgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Piece extends JLabel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    public Piece(ImageIcon icon) { super(icon); }

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    /*
     This method checks if there is a piece present on a particular square.
     */
    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y) {
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     This is a method to check if a piece is a Black piece.
     */
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    /*
     This method is called when we press the Mouse. So we need to find out what piece we have 
     selected. We may also not have selected a piece!
     */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX() / 75);
        startY = (e.getY() / 75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

    /*
     This method is used when the Mouse is released...we need to make sure the move was valid before 
     putting the piece back on the board.
     */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success = false;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

        if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
            if (startY == 1) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 6) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) {
                                if (startY == 6) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!validMove) {
            int location = 0;
            if (startY == 0) {
                location = startX;
            } else {
                location = (startY * 8) + startX;
            }
            String pieceLocation = pieceName + ".png";
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pieceLocation));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
            panels.add(pieces);
        } else {
            if (success) {
                int location = 56 + (e.getX() / 75);
                if (c instanceof JLabel) {
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png"));
                    parent = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);
                } else {
                    Container parent = (Container) c;
                    pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png"));
                    parent = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);
                }
            } else {
                if (c instanceof JLabel) {
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    parent.add(chessPiece);
                } else {
                    Container parent = (Container) c;
                    parent.add(chessPiece);
                }
                chessPiece.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Also here is a screenshot of the layout in netbeans

[image]

Any help or tips for would welcomed

Here is the Source File in which everything is written in one giant file the pieces can be moved and the white pawn moves right, that is how I know the piece is coded right i just can see to link the events know that they are separate

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
    This class can be used as a starting point for creating your Chess game project. The only piece that 
    has been coded is a white pawn...a lot done, more to do!
*/

public class ChessProject extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;


    public ChessProject(){
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane 
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            chessBoard.add( square );

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0)
                square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray );
            else
                square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white );
        }

        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        for(int i=8;i < 16; i++){           
            pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png") );
            panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);         
        }
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKing.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);
        for(int i=48;i < 56; i++){          
            pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png") );
            panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);         
        }
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKing.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackQueen.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);     
    }

    /*
        This method checks if there is a piece present on a particular square.
    */
    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y){
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if(c instanceof JPanel){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
        This is a method to check if a piece is a Black piece.
    */
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY){
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel)c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();           
        if(((tmp1.contains("Black")))){
            oponent = true;
        }
        else{
            oponent = false; 
        }       
        return oponent;
    }   

    /*
        This method is called when we press the Mouse. So we need to find out what piece we have 
        selected. We may also not have selected a piece!
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) 
            return;

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel)c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX()/75);
        startY = (e.getY()/75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) return;
         chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
     }

    /*
        This method is used when the Mouse is released...we need to make sure the move was valid before 
        putting the piece back on the board.
    */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(chessPiece == null) return;

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success =false;
        Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length()-4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

        /*
            The only piece that has been enabled to move is a White Pawn...but we should really have this is a separate
            method somewhere...how would this work.

            So a Pawn is able to move two squares forward one its first go but only one square after that. 
            The Pawn is the only piece that cannot move backwards in chess...so be careful when committing 
            a pawn forward. A Pawn is able to take any of the opponentâ€™s pieces but they have to be one 
            square forward and one square over, i.e. in a diagonal direction from the Pawns original position. 
            If a Pawn makes it to the top of the other side, the Pawn can turn into any other piece, for 
            demonstration purposes the Pawn here turns into a Queen.
        */
        if(pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")){
            if(startY == 1)
            {
                if((startX == (e.getX()/75))&&((((e.getY()/75)-startY)==1)||((e.getY()/75)-startY)==2))
                {
                    if((((e.getY()/75)-startY)==2)){
                        if((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))&&(!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()+75)))){
                            validMove = true;                   
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }                           
                    }
                    else{
                        if((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))))
                        {
                            validMove = true;                   
                        }   
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }                                                   
                    }
                }
                else{
                    validMove = false;                  
                }
            }
            else{
                int newY = e.getY()/75;
                int newX = e.getX()/75;             
                if((startX-1 >=0)||(startX +1 <=7))
                {
                    if((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))&&((((newX == (startX+1)&&(startX+1<=7)))||((newX == (startX-1))&&(startX-1 >=0)))))
                    {
                        if(checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                            validMove = true;
                            if(startY == 6){
                                success = true;
                            }                       
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))){
                            if((startX == (e.getX()/75))&&((e.getY()/75)-startY)==1){
                                if(startY == 6){
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            }
                            else{
                                validMove = false;
                            }               
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;  
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    validMove = false;
                }               
            }           
        }
        if(!validMove){     
            int location=0;
            if(startY ==0){
                location = startX;
            }
            else{
                location  = (startY*8)+startX;
            }
            String pieceLocation = pieceName+".png"; 
            pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(pieceLocation) );
            panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
            panels.add(pieces);         
        }
        else{
            if(success){
                int location = 56 + (e.getX()/75);
                if (c instanceof JLabel){
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png") );
                    parent = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);         
                }
                else{
                    Container parent = (Container)c;
                    pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png") );
                    parent = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);                 
                }
            }
            else{
                if (c instanceof JLabel){
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    parent.add( chessPiece );
                }
                else {
                    Container parent = (Container)c;
                    parent.add( chessPiece );
                }
                chessPiece.setVisible(true);                                    
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    /*
        Main method that gets the ball moving.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessProject();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: You never create an instance of `Piece` - there's no way for it to respond to any actual events and it has no relationship to any other part of your program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never create an instance of `Piece`, not even once, so it has no means by which it could ever respond to any events, it's not even on the screen...

I "think" you want to do something more like...

```
pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
```

...Note, you'll need to update `Piece` to support been constructed with a `ImageIcon`

There's also a bunch of issues with `Piece`.  You have a bunch instance fields...

```
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
JPanel chessBoard;
JLabel chessPiece;
//...
JPanel panels;
JLabel pieces;
```

Which aren't linked to anything (they are `null`) which is going to cause you no end of issues.

Instead of focusing all the management within the UI, consider trying to use more of a [MVC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The game logic, rules and state should be maintain within a model, which has NO UI logic at all.  It basically allows you to take a piece and make a move, validating that process as it goes.  It would then provide notifications back to the UI, via an [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which would notify the UI that some state has changed...

**Updated...**

Update the constructor of `Piece` so it can take a reference to an `Icon` and pass it onto it's parent, this way, you can continue using the code you already have...

```
public Piece(Icon icon) { 
    super(icon); 
}
```

Next, when you create a `Piece`, you need to install a `MouseListener` to it.  In this case, I'd be tempted to make the board responsible for the management of the pieces, it knows the layout and where all the pieces are...

```
pieces = new Piece(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
pieces.addMouseListener(this);
```

Comment: I'm Sorry, I dont understand what you mean , where would I add the code you have above and what do u mean by update Piece ? can u show me a more detailed answer using the board and piece file i have above

Comment: *"update Piece"* - basically, `Piece` does not have a suitable constructor for passing `ImageIcon`, you'll need to provide, which would basically call `super(icon)`...The above code was ripped from your source code (look for `WhiteRook.png`).  You need to change `JLabel` ro `Piece` instead...

Comment: ok so in board.java i change all the Jlabel's to Piece right ? and then how do i go about making a suitable constructor for passing ImageIcon ?

Comment: and where do I drop this into the Piece.java file ? and sorry for all the questions

Comment: Where ever you like, position is irrelevant...convention normally has it at the top of the file..

Comment: Well I have done as you have suggest but there is no change none of the pieces move in any way. But I am still getting no errors either. I have updated my code with the suggestions you gave so U can see what I did

Comment: You, it's probably because you've not registered the `MouseListener`s, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: But the MouseListners are coded I have all of this code in one big file in which the pieces move, the problem i am having is linking the events right I can provide that file if u need it

Comment: But where do you register them?  How does the system know you want to know about mouse events?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by registered I dont understand why when they are in one whole file they work and the pieces can be moved but when i try to seperate them they wont work, i have read the document u supplied i didnt see how it can help

Comment: `addMouseListener(this)` <-- Unless you register the `Piece` as a wanting to listen to mouse events, you will never receive any.  I think you need to take a longer look at the tutorials first...

Comment: i have reviewed the documention and still have no clue what you are trying to get at ??????????????????????/

Comment: You have a problem, both the board and piece have mouse handling functionality...which one is actually suppose to be doing the work...?

Comment: Ok they way I have it is the piece.java is handling the work, as board.java should just be for display, I am just having problems linking the mouseevents from the piece.java to effect the board.java. I know the events work and the moves as I have written all of this in one big file which I have linked above using just textpad etc but I now want to break it down

Comment: I'd probably make the board deal with it. Think about it like this, the board knows the layout, it knows what is on the board and where.  A `Piece` is an isolated element and shouldn't care about anything else

Comment: so i should but the all the mouse listners in the board.java file and leave the piece.java just for the movement of the pieces ?